# Proxy authenticator auntenticates HTTP But not HTTPS . Why?

Tags: java, proxy

I am using openjdk . For porxy authentication ,I am using Authenticator but for my first Request as HTTPS the authenticators doesn't authenticates and throws error. After connecting through HTTP , HTTPS working fine.

I have tried with setting system property, jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" and jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes="".

```
private static void setProxy(String proxyHostName,int proxyport){
        proxy=new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress(proxyHostName,proxyport));
    }

private static void setProxy(String proxyHostName,int proxyport,String username,String password){
        setProxy(proxyHostName,proxyport);

        if (username!=null && password!=null) {
           System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");
            System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes", "");
            Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return (new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray()));
                }
            };
            Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
        }

    }
```

Comment: java.net.Proxy @BachSlash

Comment: If its's specific for HTTP ,It shouldn't worked for HTTPS.But it's worked after my First Http request.[Https working after first Http tequest].

Comment: please help with this..... :(

Answer (score 0):

After setting this property in my java_opts in .sh file . It worked fine for me.
Orelse Anyone want to set in their java code means set it in start method.